# restrict the values by constraint using a lookup table

Tags: sql, t-sql, constraints, lookup-tables

I have a lookup table

```
Tbl_UserType_value_lookup:

UserTypeID  |AllowedValue
-------------------------
1           |x
1           |y
2           |u
3           |a
```

*(This says an user of Type `1` can enter the values of type `x` and `y` only and not of type `u` or `a`..so on)*

I have another table

```
Tbl_Activity:

UserID   |userTypeID    |value
---------------------------
```

Now in this table how can I resrtict a user of type `1` to the values as per  `Tbl_UserType_value_lookup` table using `CHECK` constraint ?

Is there any other way?

Comment: not clear, what do you want to know in the second table?

Comment: @vulkanino: in the second table I don't want to let a user of type `1` to enter a value of type `u` or `a`..but only of type `x` and `y`..

Comment: SQL Server does not currently support [subqueries in `CHECK` constraints](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/340497/support-subqueries-for-check-constraints), however foreign key is the usual short hand for this kind of constraint (and is indeed supported!), otherwise use a trigger.

Comment: @onedaywhen: how do I use the trigger for that? could you please elaborate it?

Comment: In a nutshell, write a query (perhaps multiple queries) that test for bad data. In the trigger, test that your queries are the empty set: if they are not then raise an error and rollback the transaction in the usual way. Note the trigger is fired only on the table being updated (rather than all tables involved in the trigger's queries).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have a unique key on `Tbl_UserType_value_lookup` for `UserTypeID, Allowed Value`, you could have a composite foreign key on `Tbl_Activity` that references these columns.

(ie the combination of UserType, Value would have to exist on `Tbl_UserType_value_lookup` to be insertable.

There's quite a lot of discussion of this here:

[Creating a composite foreign key in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651667/creating-a-composite-foreign-key-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: I would like to know, if its enough both `UserTypeID, AllowedValue` are just `UNIQUE`, but not `Composite Primary keys` for using them as `Foriegn key`s in foreign table?

Comment: Its fine that they are setup as a unique key - It doesn't have to be the PK that you reference.

Answer (score 0):

CHECK constraints enforce domain integrity by limiting the values that are accepted by a column. They are similar to FOREIGN KEY constraints in that they control the values that are put in a column. **The difference is in how they determine which values are valid: FOREIGN KEY constraints obtain the list of valid values from another table, and CHECK constraints determine the valid values from a logical expression that is not based on data in another column.** For example, the range of values for a salary column can be limited by creating a CHECK constraint that allows for only data that ranges from $15,000 through $100,000. This prevents salaries from being entered beyond the regular salary range.

**Use FOREIGN KEYS!**

---

**Update:**
For more info, check [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx).

Comment: Misstatement: "CHECK constraints determine the valid values from a logical expression that is not based on data in another column".

Comment: @onedaywhen this is from [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx).

Comment: @aF - agreed, the documentation itself seems to be faulty here - maybe it was written by someone who only uses column check constraints rather than table check constraints... (Actually, the next but one paragraph explicitly discusses checking across multiple columns. Even odder. And the examples are just plain confusing, seeming to try to use it as `ASSERTION` across the entire table content)

Comment: I've raised connect issue #726509 with the main issues I see there.

Comment: @aF.: it would have helped if you had posted the link to the article (also saves you from accusations of [plagiarism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism). That said, you have stated something that is materially incorrect, even if it is a verbatim quote from the vendor, therefore this answer is itself incorrect. Bottom line: you should correct the wording in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't create a dynamic `CHECK` constraint.
Use a foreign key to link `Tbl_Activity` to `Tbl_UserType_value_lookup`.

**What you want is an application rule that can't be easily enforced in the data structure.**

Answer (score 0):

Tbl_Activity:

```
FOREIGN KEY allowed_value(userTypeID, Value) 
    REFERENCES Tbl_UserType_value_lookup (userTypeID, AllowedValue)
    ;
```

(If your SQL platform supports composite foreign keys, otherwise you'll have to hack some ugly triggers and/or use a surrogate key)

BTW: avoid MixedCase in table names and column names. Normally, SQL is *not* case-sensitive, but if your database has to be moved to a case-sensitive installation, you'll cry bitter tears. Mixing MixedCase and under_scores is considered Bad_Style (by most people).