# Foreign key part of primary key

Tags: database

[SQL Table Foreign Key that is part of a Composite Primary Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12679312/sql-table-foreign-key-that-is-part-of-a-composite-primary-key/32070301#32070301)

Foreign key can be part of primary key...

Comment: What is the question? You've not actually asked anything

Answer (score -1):

No, foreign key cannot be part of a primary key