# Add FK / Constraint to subsection of table

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, check-constraints

### Setup

Here's two simplified* tables that illustrate the problem I have
<sub>*The actual tables are built such that I can't really refactor the columns or split them apart easily</sub>

#### Table: `CodeValues`

```
| CodeSet | CodeValue | CodeText |
|---------|-----------|----------|
| States  | 1         | Vermont  |
| States  | 2         | Hawaii   |
| YN      | 1         | Yes      |
| YN      | 2         | No       |
```

<sup>Where `CodeSet` + `CodeValue` are a composite primary key</sup>

#### Table: `Address`

```
| AddressID | Zip   | State |
|-----------|-------|-------|
| 1         | 96701 | 2     |
| 2         | 05001 | 1     |
| 3         | 05602 | 1     |
```

<sup>Where `AddressID` is the primary key</sup>

---

**What is the appropriate DB constraint to add to `Address.State`?**

It should *always* be a value that is present in `CodeValues Where CodeSet = 'States'`, but I don't believe I can create a [Foreign Key that is part of a Composite Primary Key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12679312/1366033)

Should it just be a [check constraint based on a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000698/sub-queries-in-check-constraint) like this?

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION checkCodeValues(
    @codeSet   VARCHAR(50),
    @codeValue SMALLINT

)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CodeValues WHERE CodeSet = @codeSet
                                          AND CodeValue = @codeValue)
        RETURN 1
    RETURN 0
END
```

```sql
ALTER TABLE Address
    WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT CK_State
    CHECK (checkCodeValues('States', State))
```

My concern is that db design tools won't really recognize the full impact of this constraint against, when it really is a FK, but just against a subsection of the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method uses a little bit more storage, but it accomplishes what you want:

```
create table addresses (
    . . .,
    codeset as (convert(varchar(?), 'states')) persisted,
    foreign key (codeset, state) references codevalues (codeset, codevalue)
);
```

The `?` is for the length of the `varchar()` column in the `codevalues` table.

Happily, you don't need triggers or user-defined functions to accomplish this.

Unhappily, you need to persist the `codeset` in each row, so that eats up a wee bit of space in the table.

Comment: Hey Gordon, so this returns the error "*`Columns participating in a foreign key relationship must be defined with the same length and scale`*" because the `persisted` computed column is a fixed width and doesn't play nice with a variable width code set name field (all codesets names aren't going to have identical lengths).  [Here's a fiddle demonstrating the issue](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ca9449/1). Any ideas how to work around that?