# check constraint for 2 columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

can anybody help me in writing a trigger on a table ,
 the scenario is like this
i have a table named person with columns col1 and col2 ,

```
Person
col1 |  col2
0    |  1
1    |  0
2    |  3
3    |  1
4    |  2
5    |  3
```

these columns col1,col2  values are dependent on another table employee columns col3 col4

```
Employee
col3 | col4
0    | 1
1    | 0
2    | 1
3    | 3
4    | 0
5    | 3
6    | 1
```

now if combination of col1 and col2 values (eg 0,1 from person table exists in employee table then do not update the columns col1 and col2 in person table ,if col1 and col2 values are  2,3 value doesn't exists in employee table ,so in this case if there is any update on columns  col1 and col2  just print a message

Comment: If we had more information on what your bigger picture goal is, we might be able to provide you with more assistance / better answers.

Answer (score 1):

This has a smell to it. Based on your question it seems as though you are trying to create a trigger for maintaining a relationship between tables. If this is the case, you should probably consider creating composite foreign keys rather than using a trigger. This post has a good example of creating composite keys: [Creating a composite foreign key in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651667/creating-a-composite-foreign-key-in-sql-server-2008) .

In my experience, Person/Employee tables typically have a 1:0..1 relationship. In this case your Person table would have a primary key; in your case the key would be composite. The employee table would have it's own primary key as well as a composite foreign key which referenced the Person table.