# Not able to create foreign key "There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table"

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key, composite-key

This is my table 1:

```
CREATE TABLE PurchasedProducts
(
   Purchase_Order_No int,
   Purchase_Product_ID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Inventory(In_Product_ID),
   Purchase_Quantity int NOT NULL,
   Purchase_Status varchar(7) NOT NULL,

   PRIMARY KEY(Purchase_Order_No, Purchase_Product_ID)
);
```

This my table 2:

```
CREATE TABLE PurchasedDate
(
    PD_PO_No int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES PurchasedProducts(Purchase_Order_No),
    PD_Date date NOT NULL
);
```

I executed the first table successfully, but when I execute the second table It is showing this error message:

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'PurchasedProducts' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK__Purchased__PD_PO__0B5CAFEA'.

I don't what is the problem is. Please help me!

Comment: It is clear, purchase_product_no column is not a primary or uniquely key in parent table,

Comment: Not related to your question, but that's a very strange database design.  A more conventional approach would be to have a purchase order table with the purchase date as one of the the fields.  Your purchasedProducts table would have a foreign key reference to it.  By the way, your answer is here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651667/creating-a-composite-foreign-key-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: @Rajesh can you please tell what does this mean `PRIMARY KEY(Purchase_Order_No, Purchase_Product_ID)`. I want both Purchase_Order_No, Purchase_Product_ID as a composite key. And I want the PD_PO_No as the foreign key of Purchase_Order_No. This for my assignment, I am new to SQL please help. Thankyou

Comment: You need to have both of them in foreign key in that case

Comment: Right, in PurchaseDate you reference a PK (Purchase_Order_No), but you don't have a PK (Purchase_Order_No), you have a PK (Purchase_Order_No, Purchase_Product_ID)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary key in your `PurchasedProducts` table is made up of two columns:

```
PRIMARY KEY(Purchase_Order_No, Purchase_Product_ID)
```

So any child table that wants to reference that **also** must have these exact two columns:

```
CREATE TABLE PurchasedDate
(
    PD_PO_No int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Purchase_Product_ID INT NOT NULL,
    PD_Date date NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE dbo.PurchasedDate
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PurchaseDate_PurchasedProducts 
    FOREIGN KEY(PD_PO_No, Purchase_Product_ID)
    REFERENCES PurchasedProducts(Purchase_Order_No, Purchase_Product_ID)
```

A **foreign key** can only reference the **whole** primary key of a parent table - you cannot reference only one column out of 2 from the parent table's PK.

Comment: @kaviraj & marc_s: A FOREIGN KEY can reference any NOT NULL UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY column set. And such a column set can be contained in larger ones. So you can reference 1 column of 2 of a PK as long as it's NOT NULL UNIQUE. SQL NOT NULL UNIQUE and PK actually declare a superkey not necessarily candidate key and FK actually declares a foreign superkey not necessarily foreign key.

Comment: @philipxy: agreed - but if that one single column in the PK already is unique and not null - ***why*** do you have a compound PK then?? That single column alone would be a better candidate for the PK in that case.....

Comment: Yes, columns in an SQL FK other than of one referenced-table CK are redundant in the sense that you could drop them but reconstruct them via JOIN with the referenced table. (Ironically such FKs appear in SQL idioms to declaratively CHECK constraints that otherwise given SQL's poor declarative constraint support would require triggers. Eg as subtable type discriminators.) But such columns might be truly otherwise needed and constrained. Ultimately the SQL terms PK and FK are just misleading and one should not infer things based on names.

Comment: (It's not that you have a compound *relational* PK in the referenced table. You have a compound SQL PK, because you have a compound superkey, because you want a compound foreign superkey referencing it, to constrain the referencing table. There's a sense in which it is tasteless to use SQL "PK" rather than "NOT NULL UNIQUE" for a non-CK; but there's also the sense in which SQL "PK" simply means superkey. So the question is really, why do you have a compound foreign superkey.)