# Does order of columns in foreign key definition matter?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, ddl

Given the following primary key definition (note the order of the columns) on `table1`:

```
ALTER TABLE "table1" ADD PRIMARY KEY ("f1", "f4", "f2", "f3");
```

Further given the following foreign key definition (note the order of the columns) on `table2`:

```
ALTER TABLE "table2"
  ADD CONSTRAINT "const1"
  FOREIGN KEY ("f1","f2","f3","f4")
  REFERENCES "table1" ("f1","f2","f3","f4");
```

---

**First Question**

Regarding the following line in particular:

```
FOREIGN KEY ("f1","f2","f3","f4")
```

Should the order of the columns typically be the exact same as the order of the columns in the primary key definition and if yes why? Will there be an index created on `table2` for that?

---

**Second Question**

Regarding the following line in particular:

```
REFERENCES "table1" ("f1","f2","f3","f4");
```

Does the order of the columns need to match the order in the primary key definition on `table1` or does this not matter and why?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the columns in your composite foreign key should be in the same order as the corresponding columns in the primary key, in the parent table.  If not, then the constraint won't work as you expect.  No, an index on `table2` will not automatically be created, but you may create one if that would help with some of your queries.

Comment: "If not, then the constraint won't work as you expect" - In what sense, exactly? The docs don't seem to mention any such limitation.

Comment: @NickBarnes I don't think we're talking about the same thing, [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651667/creating-a-composite-foreign-key-in-sql-server-2008).  `(f1, f2) -> (f1, f2)` can't possibly mean the same thing as `(f1, f2) -> (f2, f1)`, can it?

Comment: No, but I read the question as asking whether the order needs to match the order of the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint in the parent table

Comment: It doesn't, but that doesn't mean that the foreign-primary key relationship you would have setup would make any logical sense.  So, you're right, but it might not make any sense.

Comment: I don't think we're talking about the same thing either... I read the question as "can I declare `FOREIGN KEY (x,y) REFERENCES parent (x,y)`, even if the parent declares `PRIMARY KEY (y,x)`?" - as long as the order within the child table's `FOREIGN KEY` and `REFERENCES` clauses agrees, I don't think the order declared in the original `PRIMARY KEY` constraint is relevant

Comment: @NickBarnes yes you got my question right.
My second question would be: "can I declare `FOREIGN KEY (x,y) REFERENCES parent (y, x)`, even if the parent declares `PRIMARY KEY (x,y)?`

Comment: @user3193317 Yes, you can declare that, but it doesn't mean the same thing, nor might it make any sense.  But, Postgres won't stop you from doing that, assuming that `x` and `y` are both the same respective type in each table.

Comment: @user3193317: The child table might be using different column names (e.g. `FOREIGN KEY (a,b) REFERENCES parent (x,y)`), so the order there is the only thing tying them together. But the order in the referenced `PRIMARY KEY` is never relevant, as far as I know.